# Firefox 5 opens new tabs in new windows

Tags: firefox

I use Firefox 5.
Whenever I right click a link in Firefox and select "open in new tab", it opens it up in a new window.
Normally it just opens a new tab. Middle-mouse button gives the same behavior.

I made no changes. The only thing that happened is that windows 7 did its updates like usual.

How to restore the normal behavior?

Comment: This problem seemed to be generated by a javascript error I got on some site. When I restart firefox and reloaded last session it still happened. When I did not use that function it did not open them in a new window. I will test if I can find the site again.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem anymore so it seems to be ok.

Answer (score 3):

Does Firefox menu "Options" / "Tabs" / "Open links that open in a new window:" "New Tab" work for you?

I am using Firefox 5 on both Ubuntu 11.04 and Windows 7, and on both of those links open to new tab, not window.

If this does not help, then try uninstalling the Firefox, deleting all settings under :\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox, and then installing again.

Because it works for other people, it's possible it's just some old setting left lying around on your system. Remember to take backups of the settings so you can revert back to them if it didn't help.

One option is to install extension called "Tab Mix Plus". It overrides much of default behavior of the Firefox tab handling and enables overrides not present on vanilla FF.

Comment: This is enabled yes.

Answer (score 2):

Get Tab Mix Plus.  I'll force misbehaving tabs to open in the same window.

Comment: +1 This is a "must have" extension. You can control tab opening - and several other things